# Dependable spinner in Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, spinner

I'm trying to create dependable spinner in Fragment.
There are 2 spinners and value in the spinner7 depends on value in spinner3

```
public class PageFragment1 extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.page_1, container
                        , false);

        Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerAxles);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.Axles, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);
        spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner spinner7 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTrailAxle);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter7 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.TrailAxle, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter7.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner7.setAdapter(adapter7);
        spinner7.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        return rootView;

    }


@Override
    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinnerAxles);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.Axles, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);
        spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner spinner7 = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinnerTrailAxle);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter7 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.TrailAxle1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter7.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner7.setAdapter(adapter7);
        spinner7.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

String AxlesText = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();

if (AxlesText.equals("6x2")) {
Spinner spinner7 = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinnerTrailAxle);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter7 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.TrailAxle1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter7.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner7.setAdapter(adapter7);
        spinner7.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        } else {
Spinner spinner7 = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinnerTrailAxle);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter71 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.TrailAxle1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter71.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner7.setAdapter(adapter71);
        spinner7.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

}
```

The program replace drop down list in spinner7 according the value in spinner3, but I can't chose item from this drop down list.
Whatever I choose, spinner7 always showing the first item in the drop down list.

Comment: Set separate `OnItemSelectedListener` on Spinners ..  Ans if `spinner7 depends on value in spinner3` then u only need to change the adapter data in spinner7 not for spinner3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 main things to remember in solving your issue:

1. Pass in a "reference" of the your data when initializing the ArrayAdapter. eg. a List works well
2. Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` whenever the data inside your adapter
   changes

Also, you do not need to re-initialize the entire adapter on every selection. Instead, you can streamline your code like this:

```
public class PageFragment1 extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3, adapter7;
    private List<CharSequence> spinner7DataList; // Save a reference to your data here

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.page_1, container
                        , false);

        Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerAxles);
        adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.Axles, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);
        spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        spinner7DataList = new ArrayList<>(); // Initialize your data
        spinner7DataList.addAll(Arrays.asList(getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TrailAxle)));
        Spinner spinner7 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTrailAxle);
        adapter7 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner7DataList);
        adapter7.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner7.setAdapter(adapter7);
        spinner7.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Verify that the adapter that triggered this method is the one you want
        if (adapterView!= null && adapterView.getId() == R.id.spinnerAxles) {
            String axlesText = adapter3.getItem(position).toString();
            if (axlesText.equals("6x4")) {
                // Note that we are not updating the adapter here, just the list that was passed to it previously
                spinner7DataList.clear();
                spinner7DataList.addAll(Arrays.asList(getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TrailAxle2))); // Load the new data into the list
                adapter7.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Important, this will ensure that your data changes are reflected on the Spinner
            } else if (axlesText.equals("3x2")) { // Any other conditions if needed

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
```

This answer works because you are passing `spinner7DataList` by reference to `adapter7`. So whenever you manipulate the data inside `spinner7DataList`, it is reflected within the `adapter7`

Comment: Thank you very much Salil! You can not imagine how much time I spent trying to fix this issue!   And you did it just in one moment. Tons of + to your Karma!